# conditional ngClass doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li ng-class="{selected: 'checked==true'}" ng-repeat="item in data">
<span>item.name</span>
<input ng-model="checked"/>
</li>
```

I want to add class 'selected' if the checkbox is checked. But the above code added the selected class before I click on the checkbox, what's wrong?

Comment: did you try to wrap: `'selected'`?

Comment: `ng-class="{selected: checked}"`, since `checked` is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the question, you have mentioned that your input is a checkbox. If you miss type for input, it treats it as a text input.

So, your input should be like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
```

Now, if you use a ng-model for checkbox, corrosponding variable which is `checked` here, can only hold `true` or `false`, both are boolean. So, you dont need to compare them in `ng-class`.

Only 
`<li ng-class="{selected: checked}" ng-repeat="item in data">` 
would suffice.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IIEQpBJLX3Mf0r3gfdGm?p=preview) is the plunker I created for you.